# What is the difference between my code and the Bluechat sample program?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, rfcomm

I need to transfer data from an android phone to a CSR8670 development board, but I am beginner in Bluetooth, android as well as CSR chip programming
Using what rudimentary knowledge that I have regarding Bluetooth, I used this code to connect the phone to the CSR board, and it seems to work smoothly up to the pairing step. Here is the MainActivity file:

```
package com.example.bluetoothbasic1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.example.bluetoothbasic1.R;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btnCheckBluetooth;
    BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothServerSocket serverSocketForCSRComm;
    BluetoothSocket btSocketForCSRComm;
    private Set <BluetoothDevice>mypairedDevices;
    private Set <String> myArrayAdapter;
    // Register the BroadcastReceiver
    IntentFilter filter;
    boolean connectedToCSR = false;

    int i;

    InputStream btInputStream;
    OutputStream btOutputStream;

     private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000FFFF-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    // private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001F00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    // private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private static final UUID RANDOM_UUID = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnCheckBluetooth = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCheckBluetooth_id);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onStop();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("MYLOG", "INSIDE BROADCAST onReceive" );
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // When discovery finds a device,
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                Log.d("MYLOG", "FOUND DEVICE" );
                 BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Log.d("MYLOG", "CALLED intent.getParcelableExtra()" );
                // myArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());


                device.createBond();

//              try {
//                  Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
//                  method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
//              } catch (Exception e) {
//                  e.printStackTrace();
//              }

                do{

                }while(device.getBondState()!=BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Pairing complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("MYLOG", "Bonding complete" );

                // connectedToCSR = true;
                myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                Log.d("MYLOG", "CALLED myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();" );

                try {
                    // serverSocketForCSRComm = myBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("Hello world", MY_UUID);      // NOT USED
                    // serverSocketForCSRComm = myBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("random_text", RANDOM_UUID);  // NOT USED
                    // Log.d("MYLOG", "CALLEDmyBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord()" );

                     btSocketForCSRComm = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                     // btSocketForCSRComm = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(RANDOM_UUID);
                     Log.d("MYLOG", "CALLED createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID)" );

//                  btSocketForCSRComm = serverSocketForCSRComm.accept();           // NOT USED
//                  Log.d("MYLOG", "CALLED serverSocketForCSRComm.accept()" );      // NOT USED

                    btSocketForCSRComm.connect();   // this is a blocking call so when this function returns
                    Log.d("MYLOG", "CALLED btSocketForCSRComm.connect()" );


//                  Log.d("MYLOG", "btSocketForCSRComm CONNECTION VERIFIED" );
//                  
                    btInputStream = btSocketForCSRComm.getInputStream();
                    btOutputStream =  btSocketForCSRComm.getOutputStream();

                    for(i=0; i<1000; i++ ){
                        btOutputStream.write(65);
                    //  btOutputStream.wait(4);
                    }

                    Log.d("MYLOG", "CALLED btOutputStream.write(65)" );


                    btSocketForCSRComm.close();
                    Log.d("MYLOG", "CALLED btSocketForCSRComm.close()" );


//                  serverSocketForCSRComm.close();                                 // NOT USED
//                  Log.d("MYLOG", "CALLED serverSocketForCSRComm.accept()" );      // NOT USED


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    // Log.e("MYLOG", "accept() failed", e);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "REACHED EXCEPTION REACHED EXCEPTION REACHED EXCEPTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("MYLOG", "REACHEDEXCEPTIONREACHEDEXCEPTIONREACHEDEXCEPTION" );
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

            }
        }
    };



    public void btnCheckBluetooth_onCLick(View view){
         Log.d("MYLOG", "ENTERD HERE" );

        // ----- STEP 1: Detect presence of Bluetooth Adapter
        // BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); 
         myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if ( myBluetoothAdapter == null ) { 
            Toast.makeText( this, "Device does not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText( this, "Device supports Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }

        // ----- STEP 2: Enable bluetooth
        if ( !myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() ) { 
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent( BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE ); 
            // startActivityForResult( enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT ); 
            startActivityForResult( enableBtIntent, 0 );
            }

        do{

        }while(myBluetoothAdapter.getState()!=BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON);

        Log.d("MYLOG", "EXITED WHILE LOOP" );

        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);

        // ----- STEP 3: Search

//      After setting up the Bluetooth adapter, the next step is to find the Bluetooth-enabled
//      devices (CSR8670) by searching the matched Bluetooth modules.
//      Before finding a device, it needs to query
//      the list of the matched devices to make sure whether the demanded device is known to the
//      server. The following code is used to pair devices and fetch the device name.

        // This block searches in the paired devices list 
        mypairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(mypairedDevices.size() > 0){         // If there are paired devices
            // Loop through paired devices 
            for(BluetoothDevice device : mypairedDevices){
                // myArrayAdapter.add (device.getName()+"\n"+ device.getAddress());
                Log.d("MYLOG", device.getName()+"\n"+ device.getAddress() );
            }

        }
        else{
            Log.d("MYLOG", "No paired devices" );
        }

        // ----- STEP 4:
        // Start discovery
        Log.d("MYLOG", "Calling StartDiscovery");
        myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        Log.d("MYLOG", "StartDiscovery called");

//      do{
//          
//      }while(connectedToCSR != true);
//      Log.d("MYLOG", "Exited do{}while(connectedToCSR != true); infinite loop");



    }

}       // public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity { CLOSED
```

The interface has a single button, which when pressed, will:

1. Check if BluetoothAdapter is present
2. Start an Intent to enable Bluetooth
3. Get a list of paired devices (for simplicity I make sure that every time this has to be done, the CSR board is the only device around, and make sure that it has not been paired yet)
4. Start device discovery

The BroadcastReceiver called mReceiver will look for devices being discovered. For simplicity, only one device will be discoverable (the CSR board) and it will always be unpaired when discovered.

In the onReceive() function, the code

```
BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
```

will get CSR board into `device`. device.createBond(); will pair the phone with the CSR board. After pairing is complete, a BluetoothSocket is created from device, using

```
btSocketForCSRComm = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

Connection with this socket is established using

```
btSocketForCSRComm.connect();
```

After getting the input and output stream, I send a large number of bytes in this way:

```
for(i=0; i<1000; i++ ){
    btOutputStream.write(65);
//  btOutputStream.wait(4);
}
```

If I do this, a certain number of bytes gets detected by the CSR board and the detected bytes are shown on the screen in the CSR board's IDE, a larger number of bytes simply get detected but do not get displayed (I think this has something to do with how fast the CSR board can detect versus how fast the phone is sending the byte stream) and many of them just get lost. If I don't send a large continuous byte stream and just a single byte, it just seems to get lost.

Later on I tried to see if I could get the Bluechat sample program from android to detect the CSR board. The program works fine upto the device discovery phase, but some reason I still cannot find which part of the Bluechat sample program does the pairing ([see my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685427/which-part-of-bluechat-sample-program-does-pairing-of-discovered-devices)). The device.createBond() function does not seem to be present in the Bluechat sample program (the SDK IDE does not show it after the dot, which is another weirdness I haven't understood yet), but I managed to get the paring done using Method class. The main changes are in ConnectThread constructor of the connect thread class:

```
public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
    Log.d("MYLOG", "ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) CONSTRUCTOR");
    mmDevice = device;
    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

    try {
        Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    do{

    }while(device.getBondState()!=BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED);
    Log.d("MYLOG", "Bonding complete" );

    // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
    // given BluetoothDevice
    try {
        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("MYLOG", "createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID) GONE WRONG");
        Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
    }
    mmSocket = tmp;
}
```

The rest of the Bluechat code is mostly untouched, except for the custom UUID and logcat entries. If I run this program now, all the messages sent from the phone seem to get properly detected and displayed by the CSR board,and none of the data is lost.

What  exactly is the difference between my code and the Bluechat sample program, that the send data gets lost in my program while it doesn't in the Bluechat sample? As far as I understand it, it's not possible to reduce baud rate for Bluetooth RFCOMM, so the Bluechat program cannot be sending data at a lower speed. Also, how exactly does the Bluechat pair with another phone? When working with two android phones, the Bluechat sample works out-of-the-box without any modifications, but I can't understand how it is doing the actual pairing part.

I will be happy to provide any extra information.